# Tab Bar Controller linked to different views depending on user role - iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

So in my AppDelegate I have declared my tab controller and views etc
However if there is no user logged in, then the code is executed at login, however I need it to be executed again once the user has successfuly logged in.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    var navigationBarAppearance = UINavigationBar.appearance()
    navigationBarAppearance.tintColor = uicolorFromHex(0xffffff)
    navigationBarAppearance.barTintColor = uicolorFromHex(0x4183D7)

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
    let titleDict: NSDictionary = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]

    navigationBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = titleDict
    //navigationBarAppearance.clipsToBounds = true;
    let tabBarController = UITabBarController()
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Storyboard", bundle: nil)
    let myVC2 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("navProfile") as UIViewController

    let myVC1 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("navigation") as UIViewController
    let myVC3 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("navComp") as UIViewController
    var controllers = [myVC1,myVC2]
    tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers
    self.window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
    if PFUser.currentUser() != nil{
        var query = PFUser.query()
        query.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser().objectId)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (results: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            for listing in results {
                var usertype = listing["UserType"] as? String
                if usertype == "Student"{
                    var controllers = [myVC1,myVC2]
                    tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers
                    self.window?.rootViewController = tabBarController

                }
                else if usertype == "Employer" {
                    var controllers = [myVC1,myVC3]
                    tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers
                    self.window?.rootViewController = tabBarController

                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can post your solution in between `loginVC` and `nextVCs`(Multiple tabbar controllers)

Put Tabview in `storyboard`, and connect all the class like myVC1,myVC2,myVC3,

Just subview the tabbar class, and assign the class the `storyboard` `TabBatController`.

In subclassed file `- (void)viewDidLoad`, you can validate this code and load view dynamically,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    let tabbar = self.tabBarController?.tabBar
    if PFUser.currentUser() != nil{
        var query = PFUser.query()
        query.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser().objectId)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (results: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            for listing in results {
                var usertype = listing["UserType"] as? String
                if usertype == "Student"{
                    let controlrs = self.setViewControllers 
                    controlrs.removeObjectAtIndex(2)
                }
                else if usertype == "Employer" {
                    let controlrs = self.setViewControllers 
                    controlrs.removeObjectAtIndex(1)   
                }
            }
            tabbar .setViewControllers(controlrs, animated: NO);
        }
    }
}
```

HTH, Enjoy Coding !!

Answer (score 2):

Just make a bool that says that the user is logged in.
Exemple

```
var userIsLoggedIn : bool
```

You set it to true and it logs in and a if then ,there in the code

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to start with a login check. If nobody is loggged in then present a login screen from your app delegate. If somebody is already logged in, then show your normal controller hierarchy.

So in your app delegate you want 2 methods: one which creates a login controller and one which creates the normal hierarchy. Switch between the two by changing the window rootViewController. Simplest mechanism is to provide a method in your app delegate which does this for you: e.g. showLoginController and showLoggedInController. You can put the logic in these which deals with setting up a given users data for display.

The login controller can now request a switch when the login happens and the normal logged in controller can request to go back to the login screen if a user logs out: all via the app delegate instance.